# What do I do with a sample size in the form of a range（such as N=7-8） in a meta-analysis?

Tags: sample-size, meta-analysis

I would very much like you all to answer this question of mine. I found it in a 2009 paper that reported sample sizes in the form of N=7-8, N=4-8, and so on *(doi:10.1016/j.jdermsci.2009.07.001[enter link description here](https://www.jdsjournal.com/article/S0923-1811(09)00201-1/fulltext)
)*.  Meanwhile I can't find its supplementary material and raw data. Can tell me how to deal with this situation in meta-analysis?

##### The form of the data in the literature is as follows

[image]

Comment: Well, it's NOT reported as N, mean and sd, 

It's reported as group, then some number (maybe a mean) then two numbers, with a tilde, then N.  It's not at all clear what the second set of numbers are or what the tilde is for. It looks sort of like a CI, but it's nowhere near the mean, sot that's not it.

I would try to contact the authors, but, if that doesn't work, I might just not use these data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good with the syntax of the programme on this page, it seems to indicate that it's not very clear, I'll amend the question

Comment: Welcome to CV. If you know LaTeX, you can use  that between two dollar signs.

Comment: I post a picture，Actually, the SD in the table is my conversion based on the formula：sd = se * sqrt(n)

Comment: Please include a citation to that 2009 paper.

Comment: ok,I will,vary thanks for you

Comment: Unfortunately that paper is behind a pay wall. You state that you calculated the SD values. Why are there two values separated by the tilde ~? Did the original authors give two values for the SE and if so which N did you give for them? Note also that for most meta-analyses you would need the SE anyway.

Comment: I was able to download the paper through a ScienceDirect subscription. I don't see the means & std. errors reported exactly, let alone with 10 digits precision. Do you extract them from Figure 1 somehow?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience. The data for the article is in the form of an image, and I extracted the data through getdata graph digitizer, a software. The data was extracted as mean and SE respectively. the SD on my picture is based on the extracted SE and N (i.e. the calculation of the SD when N=7 and N=8). The wave symbol is an inappropriate symbol, I'm very sorry. I'll look for the data extracted from the picture and post it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is a difficult situation. There is a lot of noise in extracting the information from the paper and I think the most cautious course of action is not to use this data in the first place. In terms of what N = 7-8 actually means I'd guess that each bar in the Fig 1C (there are 4 bars, so 4 different calculations) used either 7 or 8 samples. I'd assume N = 7 for the two groups of interest (Vehicle and LR 500mg/kg).

Comment: You could try to write to the authors asking for clarification. That's probably more reliable than asking other people to guess what it means.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who came to help me. I also wrote to the author but he hasn't replied yet, I'll try to contact them again. It's a difficult problem indeed, and I didn't have a particularly good solution when I searched for advice on other forums. Personally I'm more curious as to why the authors didn't give detailed data when they reported on their research and had to be so ambiguously labelled. LOL.